# using print() after invoking recursion

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, tail-recursion

Can Someone tell me what exactly is happening here.Is the print statement executing after all the draw [3,2,1] are completed or it's happening simultaneously.I tried adding print(n) but still couldn't figure out. Is it unpacking after storing the values of ('#'*n).I am getting what I desired but just needed to understand what is actually happening

```py
def draw(n:int):
    if n<0:
        return
    draw(n-1)
    print ('#'*n)
draw(3)
```

Comment: The print is executed after draw() returns. So your results will be printed in reverse order.

Comment: Please add what kind of behavior you would expect.
It would realy help to anwer your question.

Comment: I am getting what I desired but just needed to understand what is actually happening

Answer (score 0):

the print comes after executing all the draw calls. if you want to print it in the same order make sure print comes first before calling the draw again

```
def draw(n:int):
    if n<0:
        return
    print ('#'*n)  # this should come first before the next call
    draw(n-1)
```

to understand the sequence of the recursion, follow this visualization tool. just write your provided script and run it.

https://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit

Comment: Thanks for the help. But i want it to be like this. I just want to understand what is happening. wich i still can't figure out

Comment: @jack_ I just updated my answer with a visualization that may help.